# Make parent element same width as child

Tags: html, css

So I have this sort of html

```
<div class="table-container">
  <input type="text" class="some-class"/>
  <table class="dataTable"/>
```

I want it so that the .some-class is always some percentage of the width of .dataTable(let's say 40%). I also want it so that if I append multiple table-containers(with the same children), that they appear below each other.

I've achieved the first requirement through the use of inline-block, but that means that these elements appear on the same line.

How do I achieve both?

JSFIDDLE-
http://jsfiddle.net/9xR78/

Comment: A picture (or a jsfiddle) is worth a thousand words ;-)

Answer (score 1):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/9xR78/4/

```
.parent{
    background-color : red;
    display : inline-block;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could place a `<br/>` before each new `.parent` container

**[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9xR78/3/)**

Comment: I'm relying on backbone to append the DOM element, so idk how to do this.

Comment: @praks5432 what do you mean by "append the DOM element"? can you elaborate on how you're manipulating the HTML markup in your application?